# Very weird IE7 float affecting children bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <a href="#" class="button2" title="Upgrade now">Upgrade now</a> 
    <a href="#" class="button2" title="Buy more credits">Buy more credits</a>
</div>
```

The `float:right|left` (whether inline, or in my stylesheet) seems to make the links lose both their vertical padding and their bottom border. If I remove it, I have no problem.

Here's the **CSS** for the links:

```
.button2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #064687;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px #0B5BAC solid;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #1E88F2;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6BB0F7, #2089F2);
    padding: 9px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 270px;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you still care about IE7?

Comment: You should also include more than just -moz-gradient.  Considering the low marketshare of firefox, -webkit-gradient, -ms-gradient, and gradient should also be included at the very least, and -o-gradient if you feel really specially inclined to support older opera browsers.

Comment: Or use the Compass/Sass mixin to provide the best cross-browser gradient support in 1 statement: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the old 'hasLayout' fix by adding zoom: 1;

```
.button2 {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

I don't like doing hacks like that but it seems to achieve what you want.

Comment: This worked, along with text-align:center to fix another problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are trying to assign styles to an inline element in which they typically don't apply.  Such as vertical padding, widths, and borders.  Try giving it `display:inline-block` or `display:block; float:left;`, and in the case of IE7 if you use `display:inline-block`, look for the display:inline-block fix for IE 7 and you should be all set. jsFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wUD9q/5/show/light/

FYI - Float has nothing to do with it at all.  Removing the float on the outer div doesn't fix it either.  jsFiddle for it still broken: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wUD9q/1/show/light/

Comment: Weirdly, removing the float on the outer div DID fix it for me. Must be some external factors, outside of the code I posted. I'm sure this would have worked, but I went with the solution below as making the buttons display:block; might have caused problems on other pages.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 is used by less than 1% of the world browsing the internet.  Just move on!

SOURCE: http://theie7countdown.com/

Comment: What if he's the 1%? Statistics are sometimes meaningless for individuals.

Comment: If he's comfortable with ie7 then he should also be comfortable with the drawbacks of using such an old and unsupported browser.

Comment: Although I agree completely with this statement, but sadly this is not an answer.

Comment: 2.21% of our users use IE7, which is the general public. We're about to open the new version of our site to our corporate users, where a much higher percentage are IE7 users - there are actually enough IE6 users for us to worry about that too. 1% becomes very important if it means losing or keeping a big client.